# what is default value of filedialog.askdirectory()?

Tags: python, tkinter

i wrote some code
to make GUI program

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

dirName = os.getcwd()

def getDirName():
    global dirName
    dirName = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if dirName != ####:
        lbl_1_2.configure(text=dirName)
    else:
        pass

# lbl_1_2 = Label(app, text=dirName)
# btn_1 = Button(app, text="change", width=15, command=getDirName)
```

If I close file explorer without select directory (press esc or click [x])

then a value will return to dirName.

what is it? null? 0? trash?
how can I get that value and insert to #### ?

thank you for reading

Comment: What is `filedialog` ?

Comment: oops, tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()

Comment: Please edit your code to include all imports, how are you calling `getDirName` to reduce our guesswork

Comment: btw there is no `null` in python ;)
Did you try just `if dirName:`?

Comment: @sashaaero wow. thank you so much. it works properly

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what it returns? Why do you have to ask a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the directory to whatever you want with `initialdir`:

```
dirName = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,
                                  initialdir="/path/to/start",
                                  title='Please select a directory')
```

If the user clicks <kbd>cancel</kbd> instead of <kbd>OK</kbd> then the value returned is empty.

If you want to check if a value is set simply do:

```
if dirName:
    ....
```